# How to convert Object to array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is My input Object.

```
let data = {
  "01-02-20":[{id:1}],
  "23-02-20":[{id:1}]
}
```

I am trying convert array of objects by this code

```
let res = Object.entries(data).map(( [k, v] ) => ({ [k]: v }));
```

But I didn't get my expected value :

My expected result should be like this:

```
let result = [
  {
    date: '01-02-20',
    item: [{ id: 1 }],
  },
  {
    date: '23-02-20',
    item: [{ id: 1 }],
  },
]
```

How can I get my expected result?

Comment: Why do you want `item` to be an array? Is there a way you can have more than one value in that array? Or is this just a simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `date` as key and the value as value in the resulting objects. Instead you should be using two key-value pairs, one for `date` using the key as value and one for `item` using the value as value, like so:

```
let res = Object.entries(data).map(( [k, v] ) => ({ date: k, item : v }));
```

More concise using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions):

```
let res = Object.entries(data).map(( [date, item] ) => ({ date, item }));
```

**Demo:**

```js
let data = {
  "01-02-20": [{ id:1 }],
  "23-02-20": [{ id:1 }]
};

let res = Object.entries(data).map(( [date, item] ) => ({ date, item }));

console.log(res);
```